# How to orient arrow away from a point?

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen, point-cloud-library

I have given an arrow with xyz as starting point with abc as the orientation(not the arrow tip, but a orientation vector with coordinate system origin as the origin) and a point p. I would like to orient the arrow always away from the point, but I am not sure if my solution is correct. My naive approach was this:

```
void pointArrowAwayFromPoint(Eigen::VectorXd &arrow, pcl::PointXYZRGB point){
  bool invert = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(arrow[i] < point.data[i] && arrow[i+3] > 0){
      invert = true;
      break;
    }
    else if(arrow[i] > point.data[i] && arrow[i+3] < 0){
      invert = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(invert){
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
      arrow[i] *= -1;
    }
  }
}
```

The vectorXd holds xyz in the first 3 array elements and abc in the next 3 ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first glance your solution is not working with every case. You can just simply use the appropriate vector arithmetics:

- assign your abc (which is the orientation defined as a vector starting at [0, 0, 0]) to the 3d vector
- calculate the 3d vector by subtracting your arrow origin from the POINT
- calculate angle between that two vectors

Example:

```
Eigen::VectorXd arrow(6);
// simple arrow pointing in the direction of X
arrow[3] = 1.0;
Eigen::Vector3d point{-2, 1, 1};
Eigen::Vector3d v1 = arrow.tail<3>();
Eigen::Vector3d v2 = point - arrow.head<3>();
double cosX = v1.dot(v2)/(v1.norm()*v2.norm());
std::cout << "angle between arrow and the point: " << std::acos(cosX) << std::endl;
```

If it's more than `Pi/2`, then arrow looks away.

Comment: Better use blocks: `arrow.head<3>()` and `arrow.tail<3>()`.

Comment: @ggael, yes you are absolutely right; applied suggested changes

Comment: To check if the angle is bigger than `pi/2`, you only need to check if `v1.dot(v2)<0` (no need for an expensive `acos` or dividing by the norms of `v1` and `v2`). If you are interested in the actual angle, your solution is the way to go.

Comment: Btw: `Eigen::VectorXd arrow(6);` does not zero-initialize by default. You need to write, e.g.: `Eigen::VectorXd arrow = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(6);` or `Eigen::VectorXd arrow; arrow.setZero(6);`. And for small vectors it is usually worth to specify the size at compile time: `typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 1> Vector6d;`

Answer (score 1):

Given the position of `arrow` and the position of `point`, you can get the direction pointing away from `point` simply by subtracting:

```
arrow.tail<3>() = arrow.head<3> - point.getVector3fMap();
```

You may want the orientation to be normalized, in which case you can use Eigen's [Block operations for vectors](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html#TutorialBlockOperationsSyntaxVectors) to get just abc:

```
arrow.tail<3>().normalize();
```

Comment: This won't work if the arrow is bigger then the point vector right? Otherwise i like this solution

Comment: Should work in every case, except perhaps when they are at the same point.  What do you mean when you say the arrow is bigger than the point vector? greater than? or greater in magnitude?

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is, what makes you say this won't work in some cases?

Comment: Please avoid hand loops, and use blocks: `arrow.tail<3>() = arrow.head<3>() - point.getVector3fMap();`

Comment: Ah! didn't realize that PCL points could be converted so easily. I'll make that change.